# Initial render of threejs scene doesn't add texture

Tags: three.js

I originally had an animate function in place for my three.js scene that is loaded within an AngularJS Modal, but found that after closing the Modal, the animation keeps going, and that is unneeded since I don't require constant animation like a video game would have.

At this point, I switched it to only render when someone uses the OrbitControls to move the simple box in my example, and have an initial call to render the scene so that users can see the box instead of a big blacked out square.

However, upon initial render, the texture does not appear to be applied until I use the orbit controls and move the box, at which point they appear. This is odd, since both my initial call and the listener tied to the OrbitControls are to the same function. How do I get the initial load to show the texture?

```
$scope.generate3D = function () {
    // 3D OBJECT - Variables
    var texture0 = baseBlobURL + 'Texture_0.png';
    var boxDAE = baseBlobURL + 'Box.dae';
    var scene;
    var camera;
    var renderer;
    var box;
    var controls;
    var newtexture;

    // Update texture
    newtexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(texture0);

    //Instantiate a Collada loader
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load(boxDAE, function (collada) {

        box = collada.scene;

        box.traverse(function (child) {

            if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh) {

                var animation = new THREE.Animation(child, child.geometry.animation);
                animation.play();

            }
        });

        box.scale.x = box.scale.y = box.scale.z = .2;
        box.updateMatrix();

        init();

        // Initial call to render scene, from this point, Orbit Controls render the scene per the event listener
        render();

    });

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd);
        //renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setSize(500, 500);

        // Load the box file
        scene.add(box);

        // Lighting
        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight();
        scene.add(light);

        // Camera
        camera.position.x = 40;
        camera.position.y = 40;
        camera.position.z = 40;

        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        // Rotation Controls
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        controls.addEventListener('change', render);

        controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
        controls.zoomSpeed = 5;

        controls.noZoom = false;
        controls.noPan = false;

        var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#webGL-container'));
        myEl.append(renderer.domElement);

    }

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        console.log('loaded');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `ColladaLoader` and you want to force a call to `render()` when the model and all the textures are loaded.

If you add the model to the scene in the loader callback, there is still a chance that even though the model has loaded, the textures may not have.

One thing you can do is add the following before instantiating the loader:

```
THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onLoad = function () {

    // console.log( 'everything loaded' ); // debug

    render();

};
```

Or alternatively,

```
THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

    // console.log( item, loaded, total ); // debug

    if ( loaded === total ) render();

};
```

three.js r.72

Comment: That did it, and makes sense. Thanks for adding the debug line.

Comment: There is also the onLoad callback which is executed when loaded = total: ```THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onLoad = function () { renderer.render( scene, camera ); };```

Comment: @FalkThiele Updated answer. Thank you for the suggestion.